# Is it acceptable to say “fix somebody”?

Tags: idioms

I have a problem supposed to be fixed, and I need someone to fix the problem. (Problem about my typos)

In this case, can I say “could you fix me” instead of “could you fix my writings”?

Comment: You could use "__ me" with other words, like "Could you help me." Also by the way, "writing" is usually an "uncountable noun" (https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/), so you would say "my writing," not "writings."

Comment: @AndyBonner Not necessarily. Short pieces of writing are often "writings". It doesn't sound quite right to me as OP used it, but I can't think of a good reason why not.

Comment: Yes, fix someone is used in psychobabble, too.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Right, that's why I added "usually." I feel like the plural emphasizes a collection; Oxford's example is "he was introduced to the writings of Gertrude Stein."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might occasionally hear that said in a joking way, with roughly the meaning you intend, but it's not proper English, no. You'd ask to have something specific fixed, like writing, as in your example.

Seriously talking about "fixing someone" is usually offensive, as it implies that something is so deeply wrong with them that they're "broken" or less than human.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good point.

Comment: In British English, to 'fix' someone could also be to punish them in some way, e.g. in retaliation for something. – John Brown called me a very rude name, so I'm going round to his house, and I'll fix him.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That use of fix is used in the States, too.

Comment: @Lambie Indeed. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fix+his+wagon

Comment: @AndyBonner - Didn't Americans once sometimes 'fix his clock' (around 1900)? I know 'cleaning' is more usual now.

Comment: I'd say yes: https://www.google.com/books/edition/You_All_Spoken_Here/xw8eLjzXH4IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fix+his+clock%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover, https://www.google.com/books/edition/THE_SHERIFF_S_SON/P03rJ07wJS0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fix+his+clock%22&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reports_of_Cases_Argued_and_Determined_i/uY_-78NbdZ8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fix+his+clock%22&pg=PA199&printsec=frontcover, https://www.google.com/books/edition/Plays_of_the_19th_and_20th_Centuries/2L0YAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=fix%20his%20clock

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical, and people do say it sometimes, but it sounds very blunt and harsh. "Fixing someone" implies that that person is "broken," which would generally be considered an insult.

Answer (score 0):

There is one very specific meaning of 'fix' when applied to people that is not necessarily insulting. That of rendering someone permanently infertile, generally via surgery.